# getting the id of a bootstrap tabs with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a project and using bootstrap tabs property. http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

I got this from the bootstrap.com website:

```
<div>

  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home"> AAAAAA</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">BBBBBB</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">CCCCC</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">DDDD</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

I want to get the id of the tab that is displaying and assing it to

> val id

I think i need to use javascript or jquery but i dont have any experience with any of them.

Comment: i am getting my id with in a loop which is similar to `id="content-{{$key}}"`  that's why i am having a hard time finding the id. I tried to add `onchange="myFunction{this.id)` to the div and look for it in the script as function `myFunction(id){val id = id}` but it didnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   $(".tab-pane").each(function(){
       var id = $(this).attr("id");
       // work with id

       // to modify it
       $(this).attr("id",newval)      

   })
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the active tab, using JQuery:

```
var activeTab = $(".tab-content").find(".active");
var id = activeTab.attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the id of your first div you use

```
var id = document.getElementById("home");
```

or you can use

```
var id = document.querySelector("#home");
```